# Reload JSON file using jQuery on page refresh

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

What I am trying to do here is this:

```
$.getJSON(sampleJson.json), function(data) {}
```

Read data from `sampleJson.json` display on webpage. The displayed data is changed on a webpage submitted through an AJAX call as below:

```
$.ajax({type: "GET", url: "...", data: "abc" ,
    Success: function(data) {}
```

The data is taken to server side where I used servlet to get data.
Here lies the problem, I write the data in the same `sampleJson.json` so the json file is updated. Now I want the changed data to get reflected on webpage on a page refresh since I am using the same `sampleJson.json` for display data on page load, but the webpage is not displaying the changed data.

I hope the problem is clear, is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the cached content is supplied from the second request. Add a timestamp parameter with the json url that will make the http request a fresh one everytime you request .. Like below

```
 var curTimeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
 $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/json/sampleJson.json?t="+curTimeStamp, data: "abc" ,
Success: function(data) {}
```

Comment: I am reading the json file from webapp folder , how do I add time stamp parameter here, also I tried giving json url as 'http://localhost/json/sampleJson.json?t=<timestamp> but still issue not resolved.Also tried adding '$.ajaxsetup({cache:false});' this appends timestamp at the end of line inside sampleJson.json

Comment: `$.ajaxsetup({cache:false})` is also an alternative way. By adding the timestamp, it will fetch the updated json content in that URL

Comment: Thanks Thanga. It works wen I made the json available over http. What if i use a json file in file system, will it work?

Comment: No If it is from file system, It is visible inside server only. Clients can access the json only if it is on web (http).

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the serverside serving the json file, then you can add 'no-cache' the header.

Doing this in nodejs-expressjs

```
..
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
res.json(yourdata);
..
```

but the how will depend on your serverside tech and the possibility to change it. (java?)